# How to index the following for multifaceting in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a People collection. Each person may have multiple hobbies. (e.g. Running, Climbing, Swimming, Jumping Jacks).

How would I index a single person with all those attrubutes such that I could apply a facet to them? Could someone provide a sample oh how data should be indexed given the following:

```
Person | Hobbies
Joe | Chess, Jumping Jacks, Swimming

Person | Hobbies
Bob | Rowing
```

And how I would go about being able to get facets for "hobbies" key? (note that "Jumping Jacks" is a single value, but whitespace separated word.

Comment: just as an aside: jumping jacks can't be a hobby :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you both want to search on the hobbies field and make a facet on it, you need to use a [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/). That's how you can index the same field in different ways. Usually the version for search needs to be tokenized and at least lowercased, plus language dependent analysis if you want, while the facet version doesn't even need to be analyzed since the facet entries need to be the same that you had in your source documents.

```
{
    "people" : {
        "properties" : {
            "hobbies" : {
                "type" : "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "hobbies" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
                    "facet" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above mapping would create two different fields for the same `hobbies` field as input. The first one, which you can refer to in your queries just using the `hobbies` name using the default [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer/); the second one is not analyzed and can be used for the facet. You can refer to it as `hobbies.facet`.

As a result you can search for `jumping`and find a match, but your facet will look like the following:

Chess (1)
Jumping Jacks (1)
Swimming (1)
Hobbies (1)
Rowing (1)